# Function call javascript

Tags: javascript, function, alert

I called helloworld and defined it with below two different ways:

1) With variable

2) With function name itseld

```
var helloWorld = function() {
    return '2';
}

function helloWorld() {
    return '1';
}

alert (helloWorld());  // This alert 2, but in absence of "var helloWorld = ....", it alert "1".
```

Can anyone please explain reason why it's calling var helloWord = ? and not function helloWorld () ?

Thank You !!

Comment: Read this: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 11):

*why it's calling var helloWord = ? and not function helloWorld () ?*

Because `functions` definitions will be `hoisted` to the top. And the assignments remains in the same place. So it is getting `overridden`.

This is how the interpreter sees the code,

```
function helloWorld() {
    return '1';
}

var helloWorld;

//the above function is getting overridden here.
helloWorld = function() {
    return '2';
}

alert (helloWorld());
```

Comment: There's a great demonstration of this kind of variable and function hoisting here: https://github.com/loverajoel/jstips/blob/gh-pages/_posts/en/2016-01-11-hoisting.md

Comment: [A Drop of Javascript](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting) also has an article about this.