# Can you explain this weird function declaration behavior?

Tags: javascript

Can you explain this?

```
var guessWhat = function(){ console.log('Print this!!!'); };
function guessWhat(){ console.log('Print that???'); }
guessWhat();

// output: Print this!!!
```

Both are declared on the global scope. Why is the the second line not overriding the first? Is the second function lost in limbo?

Comment: Maybe the two fo them exist but stored in different places in memory, and variable are resolved before functions ? But this may not be true on all browsers

Comment: hosting does the tricks!!

Comment: I'm thinking something about preference in `var = guessWhat`, is a local variable. Maybe takes precedence over the global function at line 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function guessWhat(){ console.log('Print that???'); } // declaration
```

This is a function declaration, it is defined before any code is executed.

```
var guessWhat = function(){ console.log('Print this!!!'); }; // literal
```

This is a function literal, it is defined at run-time.

so, the function definition gets loaded first (before any code), and the function literal afterwards, which overrides the first definition, hence this behaviour.

Read more [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: __loaded__ can not be the word...

Comment: @RayonDabre, Yes. Thanks. :)

Comment: @orr-siloni an answer to the same question elsewhere on stackoverflow that backs this one up http://stackoverflow.com/a/35704772/2646455